# getting error while executing wordcount program in hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I'm trying to execute the WordCount program for hadoop in eclipse and i'm getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at WordCount.run(WordCount.java:22)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:35)
```

I have copied the code from internet and the code seems fine however for reference i'm pasting the code here:

WordCount.java

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool{
      public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
        //creating a JobConf object and assigning a job name for     identification purposes
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), WordCount.class);
        conf.setJobName("WordCount");

        //Setting configuration object with the Data Type of output Key   and Value
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        //Providing the mapper and reducer class names
        conf.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        //We wil give 2 arguments at the run time, one in input path and other is output path
        Path inp = new Path(args[0]);
        Path out = new Path(args[1]);
        //the hdfs input and output directory to be fetched from the command line
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, inp);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, out);

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
        return 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
        // this main function will call run method defined above.
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(),args);
        System.exit(res);
  }
```

}

Comment: You can refer the example of word count execution/submission on the below link  http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/11/ways-to-write-traditional-word.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not passing proper command line arguments.

Comment: If you are talking about the missing code supplied then i'm supplying the following snippets - WordCountMapper.java and WordCountReducer.java

Comment: how you are executing your program and what command line argument you are passing in Path inp = new Path(args[0]);
        Path out = new Path(args[1]);

Comment: You can refer the example of word count execution/submission on the below link  http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/11/ways-to-write-traditional-word.html